# Angular route to file download

Tags: angular, file, routes

I would like to create a route in Angular which will lead me to download a file e.g.

route : '/myFile'

will result in downloading the file "/assets/files/test.pdf".

The redirectTo option just lets me switch to other routes so I cannot use it to get to my files.

I know that I could create a component for this file and then in the component just let it download but I was hoping to solve this using the routes since there are many files and I dont want to create a component for each one.

Does anyone know if this is possible in Angular?

Comment: How do you intend to trigger the file download? Via an `<a>` tag, or from code?

Comment: Neither .. the idea is that I can send the link (e.g. www.myurl.com/myFile ) to a customer and he will download the file test.pdf which filename might change for example with a version (e.g. test-v2.pdf) but the link stays the same .. ofc the route would have to be updated to new filename

Answer (score 0):

The Angular router was not build for this. It only allows navigating from one view to another according to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router).

You don't have to make a separate component for every file. Depending on your use case you could make a "download button" component, which takes an filename as input and uses a service to get the corresponding download link.

Something like:

download-button.compoment.ts:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, inject, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {DownloadService} from "../download.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download-button',
  standalone: true,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <button (click)="downloadFile()">download {{ filename }}</button>`
})
export class DownloadButtonComponent {
  @Input() filename: string | undefined;

  private readonly downloadService: DownloadService = inject(DownloadService);

  downloadFile(): void {
    if (this.filename) {
      const url: string = this.downloadService.getUrl(this.filename);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url
      a.download = url.split('/').pop();
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
  }
}
```

download.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DownloadService {
  getUrl(filename: string):string {
    // logic to get the URL here
    const url = "http://www.test.com"
    return url
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files are stored in the `assets` folder then visiting a link to it should automatically start a download without any need to configure anything.